# ASP.Net MVC Remote Validation submitting incorrect URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am following [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) walkthrough on how to implement Remote Validation.  The remote validation method fires when expected, but it is requesting the wrong url.  It is requesting

```
/Validator/IsUID_Available
```

instead of

```
http://localhost:23615/Validator/IsUID_Available.
```

This results in a 404 not found error. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you show us your validater controller class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry my bad!  I was registering the Remote attribute incorrectly as follows:

```
[Remote("IsUID_Available", "ValidationController")]
```

instead of the correct way like this

```
[Remote("IsUID_Available", "Validation")]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would venture to say that your url is correct.  Its just giving a relative url which should resolve correctly.  I'm guessing you have something wrong with your controller or you haven't registered your controller in your routes table correctly.